# why use properties over hashtable when getting initial context

Tags: properties, hashtable, jndi, initial-context

I wrote a client to get EJB's deployed in JBoss. I referred to examples in internet. Almost all of them use Properties class to define the URL and initial context factory. I want to know why properties is preferred over hashtable as here we are not storing it to file or reading from it?
One sample in internet is -

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
"com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory");
props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "file:///");

// Create the initial context from the properties we just created
Context initialContext = new InitialContext(props)
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't 'preferred'. It's much the same thing. Properties extends Hashtable. See the Javadoc.